Where can I find bottom channel weatherstrip for a steel entry door?
I have a steel entry door from my garage to basement. Door is 1.75" thick and has a channel nearly the width of the door and about .75" deep. It had weatherstrip in the channel, "U" shaped, but with the closed end glued and screwed inside the channel, to the door bottom, and the "flaps" hanging down, about 1". I can't find this type of weatherstrip, or even a depiction of it, anywhere. Any suggestions on replacement?



Maybe a garage door weatherstrip would fit.

Can you show us how the sweep was actually fitted to the door?

You can see a remnant of the torn rubber still held into the channel by a screw and glue. These 2 photos actually align in the way the rubber piece was fitted inside the channel. The "bottom" of the "U" was up against the bottom of the door, in the channel.  The "open ends" of the "U" hang down and made contact the threshold. Nothing showed on the door faces at all.

Frankly it just looks like a flat strip pressed into place and glued. It may have been pre-formed, but that doesn't seem like a requirement for a new seal to me. I would endeavor to replicate it using soft rubber or neoprene.

Lay a slice of the original part flat and measure its width.

Find suitable material (even a soft floor mat or overhead door seal), and use a straightedge to cut a new strip with the same width.

Install using sheet metal screws and an aluminum backer bar. 1/8" x 1" would probably do very well. Pre-drill the bar, and let the screws' pilot or self-piercing points punch the steel of the door.

Optionally fill the remaining cavity with foam tape or similar to add insulation value and support the sweeps.


You could use some hot-melt glue to hold the new strip in place while you fiddle with the metal bits.

Thanks for the ideas! I have been coming to the conclusion that I may have to just customize something.  I was figuring I didn't have the only door in the world made like this, but go figure...
